# html ondragout event?

Tags: html, events

I have a table that will contain elements dragged into each cell by the user.

```
<td ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="dragOver(event)" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='grey';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='white';"></td>
```

When the user mouses over a cell, I want it to turn grey. When the mouse exits the cell i want it to turn white again.

Likewise, when a user drags an element over a cell, i want it to turn grey. The problem i'm having is turning it white again after the user moves to another cell. Is there some kind of `ondragout` event in html ?

Thanks

Answer (score 30):

I just found the `ondragleave` event.

Comment: Was not an stupid question else you will not get 10 upvotes

Comment: Actually it was useful for me, it wasn't showing that event in webstorm intellisense, Thanks!